# Optimized way to select distinct records

Tags: sql, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a table in hive with 23 columns out of which 5 columns make up the composite primary keys. 
what is the best optimized way to select all the distinct records  from the table.

Comment: What is the real question? what is the issue you are dealing with?

Comment: the issue is there are duplicate records in the table . I just want to select the distinct records with all columns based on the 5 keys.

Comment: As I have already posted my solution on my own , i believe -ve votes should be made +ve.

Answer (score 1):

```
select  *

from   (select  t.*
               ,count(*) over (partition by Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5) as cnt

        from    tablename t 
        ) t

where   t.cnt = 1
;
```

Comment: Thanks @Dudu, But i already got the solution. Its almost similar approach what you have given.

select t1.*  from (select cbcih_bup_sty_clr_slsinv_snps_hist.*, row_number() over (partition by glbl_sty_clr_hash_key, wk_end_dt_hash_key, pln_ver_cd,pln_cc_id,prc_stat_cd) as rank from db_plancnsl.cbcih_bup_sty_clr_slsinv_snps_hist where  epoc_id=1481608497) t1 where rank = 1;

Comment: This a different thing. I thought that you want only rows that don't have duplicates over the 5 columns.

Comment: Yes, your solution just picks out the rows where the count is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use the group by statements with where statements where count(1)>=1 this will give you the distinct records based on your composite key.

Like

```
Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Count(1) from tablename group by Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5 having Count(1)>=1
```

Comment: but i want to get all the table columns in the select statement . the group by is just on 5 columns